# C# SQL Server input

Tags: c#, sql-server, invalidoperationexception

I am testing using a SQL database in C#. I followed the instructions from the MSDN to doing so. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqConsoleApp
{
    [Table(Name = "DesanoDict1")]
    public class DesanoDict1
    {
        [Column(Storage = "_Desano")]
        public string Desano
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_Portuguese")]
        public string Portuguese
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_English")]
        public string English
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_Spanish")]
        public string Spanish
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Use a connection string.
            DataContext db = new DataContext
                (@"C:\Users\FieldLingLab\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GUI Test\GUI Test\Resources\Desano\Desano.mdf");
            Table<DesanoDict1> dd1 = db.GetTable<DesanoDict1>();

            IQueryable<DesanoDict1> DesQuery = from des in dd1
                                               select des;


            foreach(DesanoDict1 dd in DesQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Desano={0}, Portuguese={1}. English={2}, Spanish={3}", dd.Desano, dd.Portuguese, dd.English, dd.Spanish);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The database is an mdf file from SQL Server 2014. It's a table with four columns (Desano, Portuguese, English, Spanish) and they each have words them in (I believe) UTF-16 encoding (nvarchar in SSMS). The problem I'm getting is that when I run, I get a runtime error on the `GetTable` line saying "Bad storage property: "_Desano."" Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: Your edit has fundamentally changed the question and invalidates the answer - if you have a new problem, then ask a new question.

Comment: fair enough. Can I revert to a previous edit?

Comment: Wait it seems you already have. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure because I didn't run it, but according to the msdn example it looks like you actually need to define the storage private field. like so

```
private string _Desano;

[Column(Storage = "_Desano")]
public string Desano
{
    get;
    set;
}
```